# help with type of window dialog resource needed

Tags: c++, c, windows, api

I am writing a windows program (no mfc) and need to output a status line to the operator every few seconds or so.  I tried using rich text boxes but after so many hours it seems to hang up.  Does anybody have an suggestions on what I can use instead?

People mentioned that my buffers might have been exhausted.  I thought I had planned for that.  After I had about 1000 lines displayed I would take the first 500 and remove them using the select and cut options in rich text boxes.  I still ran into the same problem.

Comment: Maybe after hours the rich text box is full?

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139006/richtextbox-limit-of-characters) appears relevant, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837086/c-loading-a-large-file-into-a-wpf-richtextbox) too. But they don't give any concrete recommendations for an alternative to rich text boxes.

You might try the **Scintilla control** (scintilla.org) which does not appear to have any hard limitations on text size. It has a permissive license. It is used by many text editors such as Notepad++, Notepad2, Code::Blocks, FlashDevelop. I haven't tried it personally but there from the documentation it looks easy to use it in a Windows API application. Of course, it might be overkill for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep appending to the text in the control every few seconds for hours then you are probably running into some memory constraint on the control or the process. I think you would have this problem with any control you choose given update frequence and how long you're running the program.

Have you considered implementing a simple circular buffer for the content of the text box?  Say only keep the last hour's messages. You could maintain a separate log file for history if the operator needed to go back in time for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own control to do this, essentially duplicating the Output window in Visual Studio. It was a success, but it ended up being much more code than I thought it would be when I started - I insisted on features such as auto-scrolling when the cursor was on the last line, select/copy, bold text, etc. It was backed by a `std::deque` so I could limit the number of lines stored for the window.

Unfortunately the code belongs to a former employer so I can't share it here.